# Kernel (Assembly Language)

Tags: assembly, operating-system, virtualbox

I just finished coding a simple Kernel in assembly language but I'm confused about one thing.

I want to see if the kernel boots with no errors or anything, so I want to make it a disc image file that can be booted on Oracle Virtual Box.

Do I just download a disc image maker and turn the folder containing the Kernel into a disc image and that's it? Or are there more steps to it?

**Here is the Kernel and the folder it's in (a folder on the desktop):**

[image]

Comment: What does the user documentation for Oracle Virtual Box say to do?

Comment: Without this image I would have been helpless.

Comment: Like do I just make it all an iso?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "kernel"?  Did you also write a boot loader that fires off the main kernel?  If so, you can assemble all that and make it disk image to be run.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to assemble (compile) your kernel.

Then, you have to find a bootloader that is capable of loading it. Grub2 is a good option. You'll have to be certain that your kernel is in an executable format that the bootloader knows how to load (in the case of Grub, the format is ELF if I recall correctly).

Then, you have to format a disc image (loading a Linux CD image on your VirtualBox) so that it can receive your kernel, and copy your kernel to it, and configure the bootloader.

*Then* you will boot your kernel, using the bootloader.

Does not seem so simple, to me...

Comment: Sorry for my lack of knowledge but how do you compile assembly code? And I just wrote a boot loader as well so that should work.

Comment: There are assemblers (assembly compilers). If you are using Windows, the most common assembler is called [nasm](http://www.nasm.us/). In Linux, there is [as](http://linux.die.net/man/1/as) (GNU assembler).